# Rational numbers via equivalent classes

Tags: rational-numbers

Sometimes the rational numbers $\mathbb{Q}$ are defined via equivalent classes $[(a.b)]\subset\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$ of integers. In general we have $(a_1,b_1)\sim (a_2,b_2):\Leftrightarrow a_1b_2=a_2b_1$.

How does such a class $[(a,b)]$ looks like if $\gcd(a,b)=1$?

Comment: Are you looking at the subset of $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$ of pairs $(a,b)$ such that $\gcd(a,b)=1$ or just the equivalence class in $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$ provided $\gcd(a,b)=1$?

Comment: Also, rational numbers are equivalence classes of $\mathbb{Z}\times(\mathbb{Z}\setminus\{0\})$ to avoid $\frac{0}{0}$.

Comment: Hint: how did you learn to simplify fractions back in Elementary school?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The class looks like this:

$$\{\dots(-2a, -2b), (-a, -b), (a, b), (2a, 2b), (3a, 3b)\dots\}$$

---

Also, every equivalence class $C$ can be written as $[(a,b)]$ such that $\gcd(a,b)=1$. This is pretty easy to show and good practice!

Comment: But I thought that every class looks like $\{...(-2a,-2b),(-a,-b),(a,b),...\}$?

Comment: @R.A. How is that different from what I wrote?

Comment: It is not at all but in my excercise I shall answer two questions: How does a general class looks like and how does a class with the gcd condition looks like. So the answer is that there is no difference?

Comment: @R.A. Well, there's a difference in that if $\gcd(a,b)=d\neq 1$, then the equivalnce class also contains $(\frac{a}d, \frac bd)$ which is not in $\{\dots(-2a, -2b), (-a, -b), (a, b), (2a, 2b), (3a, 3b)\dots\}$.

Comment: @R.A. But the point of the exercise is that all equivalence classes contain a representative $(a,b)$ such that $\gcd(a,b)=1$.